# C++ Complex Number Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload the >> and << operators for use in a complex number class. For some reason my << and >> functions cannot access the real and imaginary parts of the complex objects even though I've made them friends of the class.

Complex.h:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

class Complex
{

friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &c);
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Complex &);

public:
     explicit Complex(double = 0.0, double = 0.0); // constructor
     Complex operator+(const Complex &) const;
     Complex operator-(const Complex &) const;

#endif
```

Complex.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Complex.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

istream &operator>>(istream &input, Complex &complex) // input
{
     cout << "enter real part:\n";
     input >> complex.real;
     cout << "enter imag part: \n";
     input >> complex.imaginary;
     return input;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Complex c)     //output
{
     out<<"real part: "<<c.real<<"\n";
     out<<"imag part: "<<c.imag<<"\n";
     return out;
}
```

Comment: The canonical way to declare these operators is to have named member functions like `istream & read( istream &inp )` and `ostream & write( ostream &out ) const` that do all of the work and then, at the same namespace scope but outside of the class, have an overload of `operator>>` that calls read and an overload of `operator<<` that calls `write`.

Answer (score 2):

You *didn't* friend the same function you defined.  You friended the first, and defined the second:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &c);
       std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out,       Complex  c)
```

Also, Is the member named `imaginary` or `imag`?

```
 input >> complex.imaginary;
 out<<"imag part: "<<c.imag<<"\n";
```

Comment: So in .h I should have:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Complex &);
and in .cpp I should have:
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &c)

Comment: @user2276280: yes.  As it is, the compiler thinks they're unrelated functions.  The signatures have to match. (Though the `friend` only goes in the declaration`.